# Bulk insertion in laravel eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

Please see the below details for data insertion.

I have to insert multiple records on two different tables at same time or optimized way.

Let's assume 2 tables : Table A, Table B.

Table A has 1 to many relationship with Table B.

Table A column : colA1
Table B column : colB1

```
Input : 
[ 
   { "colA1": "AAA1","colB1":"BBB1" },
   { "colA1": "AAA1","colB1":"BBB2" },
   { "colA1": "AAA2","colB1":"BBB3" },
]
```

Expected output :

Table A:(parent).

```
Id  |  name  
 1  |  AAA1   
 2  |  AAA2
```

Table B:(child)

```
Id | Table A id | name   
1  |      1     |  BB1  
2  |      1     |  BB2  
3  |      2     |  BB3
```

We can achieve the bulk insertion by using insert or createMany methods for single table but i want to insert  into two tables for designed relations

Comment: However, if you want to create the relationship between them, you need to get the parent id  first, and the parent_id will be generated after you create the parent record, so you can `createMany` in each parent. Or you can bulk insert them all, and find the relationship by their names, then update the related foreign_key I think.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Here my objective is don't want to iterate one by one (DB Call)  to insert parent and child association because requirement is user can upload excel file with huge amount of input dateset. Please let me know, Is there any other way to handle this with query builder/optimized solution.